# Is it possible to drag and drop external data into a jstree?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, cakephp, jstree

I'm working on a project which requires a hierarchical navigation menu to be built. [jstree](https://www.jstree.com) looks good for this.

The tree will be saved to a database - I am planning on using CakePHP's [Tree Behaviour](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html) (the project has to work in Cake 2.x rather than 3.x due to the existing codebase).

One of the things I need to do is have the ability to add "Tags" to my tree from an external data source.

The way I have things configured is as follows:

The data to populate my jstree is coming from a database table (called `navigations` due to Cake's naming conventions). It uses the table structure given on the Tree Behaviour link above.

I'm loading this data into a jstree with the ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "/ajax_get_tree",
    dataType : "json",    

    success : function(json) {
        createJSTrees(json);
    },    

    error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});


function createJSTrees(jsonData) {
    $("#tree").jstree({
        'core': {
            "check_callback" : true,
            'data' : jsonData
        },
        "plugins" : ["dnd"]
    }).on('loaded.jstree', function() {
        $("#tree").jstree('open_all');
    });
}
```

What I want to do is drag and drop "Tags" (by which I mean list items) from a separate div, `#tagList` into elements on the tree. The tag data is formatted as follows:

```
<div id="tagList">
    <li data-tag="1">United Kingdom</li>
    <li data-tag="2">France</li>
    <li data-tag="3">Germany</li>
</div>
```

I know it's possible to use things like jqueryui's [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) behaviour to move them from one div to another (from `#tagList` into `#tree`).

However, I don't know how I can "drop" the tag such that jstree lists it under the appropriate node.

For example I've tried this - which is just using jqueryui and has nothing to do with jstree other than referencing the div it's running on:

```
$('#tagList li').draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: 'clone',
        connectToSortable: "#tree",
    });
```

My question really is whether what I'm trying to do is even possible? I've spent a long time looking into this and feel I'm getting nowhere with it.

Are there any other things out there that can do this type of task? I've had a look but was unable to find anything. Essentially the requirements are the ability to create a tree (name, edit, delete, drag/drop) but then to also bring Tags (`<li>` elements from the `#tagList`) into it, and save it.

Comment: This can be done in a sense. You will need to have a "drop" target, and when you `drop` an item upon it, this will trigger a callback that can perform tasks. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is your `core` supposed to have `data: { data: function() }`?

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624813/how-to-drag-a-node-from-a-div-and-drop-it-on-to-a-jstree-jstree-version-3-0-4

Comment: Also found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/DVt_IVboAFI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the articles I posted in the comments, you need to create an object that jsTree will be familiar with.

Reference:

- [How to drag a node from a div and drop it on to a JStree? (jstree version: 3.0.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624813/how-to-drag-a-node-from-a-div-and-drop-it-on-to-a-jstree-jstree-version-3-0-4)
- [Dragging a foreign object into JSTree problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/DVt_IVboAFI)

Working Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/dLv7xk3t/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <div class="ui-widget-header">
    Tags
  </div>
  <div id="tagList">
    <ul>
      <li data-tag="1" id="uk-1">United Kingdom</li>
      <li data-tag="2" id="france-1">France</li>
      <li data-tag="3" id="germany-1">Germany</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <div class="ui-widget-header">
    Tree
  </div>
  <div id="tree">
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var exData = [{
  id: "loc1",
  parent: "#",
  text: "Location 1"
}, {
  id: "loc2",
  parent: "#",
  text: "Location 2"
}, {
  id: "italy-1",
  parent: "loc2",
  text: "Italy",
  icon: "fa fa-flag"
}, {
  id: "poland-1",
  parent: "loc2",
  text: "Poland",
  icon: "fa fa-flag"
}];

function makeTreeItem(el) {
  return $("<a>", {
    id: $(el).attr("id") + "_anchor",
    class: "jstree-anchor",
    href: "#"
  });
}

$(function() {
  $('#tree').jstree({
    core: {
      check_callback: true,
      data: exData
    },
    types: {
      root: {
        icon: "fa fa-globe-o"
      }
    },
    plugins: ["dnd", "types"]
  });
  $('#tagList li').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(e, ui) {
      var item = $("<div>", {
        id: "jstree-dnd",
        class: "jstree-default"
      });
      $("<i>", {
        class: "jstree-icon jstree-er"
      }).appendTo(item);
      item.append($(this).text());
      var idRoot = $(this).attr("id").slice(0, -2);
      var newId = idRoot + "-" + ($("#tree [id|='" + idRoot + "'][class*='jstree-node']").length + 1);
      return $.vakata.dnd.start(e, {
        jstree: true,
        obj: makeTreeItem(this),
        nodes: [{
          id: newId,
          text: $(this).text(),
          icon: "fa fa-flag-o"
        }]
      }, item);
    }
  });
});
```

The function `makeTreeItem()` is simply a wrapping function to make the item dragged in more like what jsTree already has.

The first thing to do is update the core preference to enable the creation of new nodes etc:

`check_callback: true`

The next key here is in the draggable `start` callback. This is where we create a Drag n Drop element that jsTree is already ready to handle, making use of the `dnd` plugin for jsTree.

```
  start: function(e, ui) {
      var item = $("<div>", {
        id: "jstree-dnd",
        class: "jstree-default"
      });
      $("<i>", {
        class: "jstree-icon jstree-er"
      }).appendTo(item);
      item.append($(this).text());
      var idRoot = $(this).attr("id").slice(0, -2);
      var newId = idRoot + "-" + ($("#tree [id|='" + idRoot + "'][class*='jstree-node']").length + 1);
      return $.vakata.dnd.start(e, {
        jstree: true,
        obj: makeTreeItem(this),
        nodes: [{
          id: newId,
          text: $(this).text(),
          icon: "fa fa-flag-o"
        }]
      }, item);
    }
```

Basically, we have a `div` with an icon and the text of the item being dragged. This will represent our helper that will be seen while dragging. We then make and `return` an Event Object with specific attributes that jsTree will understand and our helper item.

Comment: This is really excellent - thank you so much, very much what I was trying to do. Where you have "Location 1" and "Location 2" I also need to be able to add other locations (with a form `text` input and button). Would this be a case of appending these items to `exData`?

Comment: Yeah I need to be able to add other locations. I tried using `exData.push({
  id: "loc3",
  parent: "#",
  text: "Another location"
});` but it wouldn't appear on the tree. I tried refreshing it with various methods such as `$('#tree').jstree(true).refresh();` but that just takes it back to the original state. So how can I add more data to the tree?

Comment: You can create an object and make use of append in much the same way that is done in the drag stop.

Comment: Thanks, I think I managed it following this: http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/223/

Comment: is there any way to access the ID of the parent element that the node is dropped under? For example if I drop 'United Kingdom' under 'Location 2', I need to know that 'Location 2' is the parent containing 'United Kingdom'. I guess this works using some kind of "drop" event handler?

Comment: @Andy I would review the documentation. Should be a way.

Comment: I'm going to open it as a new question. The jstree documentation is really poor.

Comment: @Andy can't argue you with you there. Based on this, http://www.powiat.chelm.pl/jstree/demo/move_copy.html, you want to make use of the `onmove` callback and event.

Comment: I've finally got it working using `$('#tree').on('copy_node.jstree', function (e, data) { ... });`. The link you provided was of help, as was the one in the Google Group on your answer. This was also interesting but didn't work for me: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/1510