# jqueryUI and jstree - Finding ID of parent where an element has been dropped

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jstree

I'm opening a new question for this although it's based on work I've been doing around [Is it possible to drag and drop external data into a jstree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291316/is-it-possible-to-drag-and-drop-external-data-into-a-jstree/47295422)

So as per the above post I have a jstree and am using jquery-UI to drag-and-drop list items from an external `<div>` on to my tree.

(Background info: when I opened the original post my plan was to save the entire tree in one go with a "save" button. However I have modified it all so each interaction fires an ajax request to save/update a database that stores the tree).

The person who answered the previous post created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/dLv7xk3t/9/

What I'm trying to do is obtain the ID of the parent node in the tree after dropping an item on to it.

Using the fiddle code as an example the data which can be dragged is made up of list items inside a div with the ID `#tagList`:

```
<div id="tagList">
  <ul>
    <li data-tag="1" id="uk-1">United Kingdom</li>
    <li data-tag="2" id="france-1">France</li>
    <li data-tag="3" id="germany-1">Germany</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The tree is running on a div with the ID `#tree`. If I was to drag "United Kingdom" from `#tagList` and drop it inside `#tree` underneath, for example, "Location 2" it looks like this:

[image]

What I need to do is get the ID of "Location 2" (the parent) upon dropping "United Kingdom". In this case the ID would be `#loc2`. I also need to know the ID of the element that's been moved, "United Kingdom" which would be `#uk-1_anchor`.

The jstree documentation is quite poor and unsurprisingly isn't designed with this particular use case in mind! I've considered using the `droppable` method of jquery-UI to see if I can detect when a list item is dropped into `#tree`, for example:

```
$( "#tree" ).droppable({
    accept: ".ui-draggable",
    activeClass: "draghover",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('dropped');
    }
}
```

This doesn't work (it doesn't do the `console.log()` upon dropping something on to `#tree`). I don't even know whether I'm going about this the correct way, or if there's something in jstree itself which would make this easier. As mentioned, I cannot see it in the documentation.

I also took a look at [How to drag a node from a div and drop it on to a JStree? (jstree version: 3.0.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624813/how-to-drag-a-node-from-a-div-and-drop-it-on-to-a-jstree-jstree-version-3-0-4) specifically trying to use `$(document).on('dnd_stop.vakata', function(e, data) {  ... });`. The problem with this is that it works for other interactions on the `#tree`, e.g. re-ordering. It's not specific to dragging and dropping from `#tagList`.

Where can I go from here?

jstree version is 3.2.1, jquery 1.12.4 and jqueryUI 1.12.1

Answer (score 0):

In `dnd_stop.vakata` event, you have enough info to check if the element being drop is from the jstree or if it's something else. The event is built much like many jquery-ui event, meaning you have the `ui` parameter which is an object containing info about the event. So you have `element`, which tells you which element is dropped and `target`, which tells you where it is dropped. From there, something like this should allow you to make proper validation:

```
$(document).on('dnd_stop.vakata', function(e, ui) {
    if (ui.element.classList.contains('ui-draggable')) {
       console.log($(ui.event.target).closest('[aria-level=1]').attr('id'));
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5g1kkapb/3/

Comment: Is there no way to get the drop location from the data object. This seems hacky